# Swf manipulation and decompression

Tags: flash, decompiler

I've been reading into swf files and how they work, and I've been searching around for good decompression libraries. However I can't seem to find any, so my question is this. Does anyone know of any well-documented swf-specific libraries that are up to date, or could I use zlib to code a decompiler myself (swfs use zlib streams)
Thanks in advance, adil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adobe have made [the specification for the SWF file format (up to v10)](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/swf.html) available on their website, so if you want to code a decompiler yourself you can use that as a basis for it.